# Hilkhot R. Yehudah in Raavad

Tags: rishonim

Who is the author of הלכות הר"ר יהודה זצ"ל quoted by the Raavad cited by the Shibbolei Haleket (Tfillah 5)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Newer editions of the Shibollei Haleket note that it refers to the Sefer Haittim of R. Yehudah Albargeloni who writes that which he is quoted by the Ravad.

Comment: Incidentally the quote from the "Raavad" is really from R. Avraham av beis din, even though it mistakenly printed as R. Avraham Ben David.

Comment: @mevaqesh >R. Avraham av beis din is this rabbeinu abrohom ban ho rambom zl?

Comment: @MoriDoweedhYaa3qob Sorry. I didnt mean to get Maimonideans out there excited. It is [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham_ben_Isaac) R. Avraham Ben Yitzchak of Narbonne the father in law and rebbi of the raavad baal hahasagos. Interestingly, I believe that R. Yoseph Qafih published his t'shuvos.

Comment: @mevaqesh yes he did. it shows even though yaman was on the rambom's zl side they still learned the other way and have manuscripts to prove it. not only that it shows that mori qafih zl doesnt have any maimonidean agenda as he is publishing the manuscripts of one of the main antagonists of rambom zl

Comment: @MoriDoweedhYaa3qob speaking of R. Qafih z"l, I greatly appreciated his masterfull commentary on the Mishneh Torah, I was wondering which of his other writings exist. For example, I have seen volumes of his writings referenced, but couldnt fond them online. Do you know which of his other writings are available, particularly for free. I would also love to know more about this great talmid chacham. Would you know where to start?

Comment: get in touch with me when you are free so i can send you my pdf collection with most of mori qafih's zl scholarly papers and some of his published stuff(not all have been digitized) as well as biographies on him